# Any way to access podman containers as a non-root user without rootless?

Tags: docker, podman

I'm trying to convert from a docker-compose 5 services setup (web app, db, cache, elasticsearch, mail) to podman, and I'm having some problems.

```
services:
  sugar:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/images/app/Dockerfile.local
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=webuser
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=webuser
      - DB_HOSTNAME=mysql
      - SMTP_HOST=mail
      - SMTP_PORT=1025
```

The files in `.` on the host system are owned by `uid=1000`, so if I trying to run podman rootless they end up being owned by `uid=0` inside of the container which of course doesn't work as the `webuser` can't manage files owned by `root`.

If I run podman as root (i.e. `sudo docker-compose up`) then everything works fine, however I constantly have to `sudo` to interact with the containers, for example running `exec` for unit tests or `ps`.

With docker, I could just add my non-root user to the `docker` group.  Is there something similiar with podman?  I've tried searching but every result refers to running podman root-less which isn't going to work in this case (unless I'm doing something horribly wrong).